# Coupons validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have created coupon controller in angular js. But i'm facing validation problem of input. When i click on Apply coupon button then it alert data success even if input field is empty and also value doesn't match..

```
/** Angular.js
 * Coupons Controller
 */

myapp.controller('couponsController', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.applycoupons = function(code){
        var couponurl = 'coupons/'+code;
        $http.get(couponurl).then(function(response) {
            if(response.data.value = 'coupons/Abeer'){
             alert('success');
            }else{
                alert('not success');
            }
});

}


});

CART HTML:
<div class="apply_cupn" ng-controller="couponsController">

              <input type="text" ng-model="code" placeholder="Coupon Code...">
              <button class="" ng-click="applycoupons(code)">apply coupon</button>

        </div>
```

Comment: `=` is assignment. You if statement is `if ('coupons/Abeer') {` Get a linter built into your IDE, it would catch things like this.

Answer (score 1):

You are accidentally assigning a value in the line

```
if(response.data.value = 'coupons/Abeer'){
```

In order to actually check if the value is correct you are going to need two equal signs.

Comment: does it still fail in the same way or is there another sign of unwanted behaviour?